# How to make a div with no content have a width?

Tags: html, css, width, css-float

I am trying to add a width to a `div`, but I seem to be running into a problem because it has no content.

Here is the CSS and HTML I have so far, but it is not working:

### CSS

```
body{
margin:0 auto;
width:1000px
}
ul{
width:800px;
}
ul li{
clear:both;
}
.test1{
width:200px;
float:left;
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="test">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="test1">width1</div>
        <div class="test1">width2</div>
        <div class="test1">width3</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="test1"></div>
        <div class="test1">width2</div>
        <div class="test1">width3</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="test1"></div>
        <div class="test1">width2</div>
        <div class="test1">width3</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just add a height value

Answer (score 187, accepted):

a div usually needs at least a non-breaking space (&nbsp;) in order to have a width.

Comment: use "display:inline-block"

Comment: good solution,if i use " " instead of &nbsp; it does not work.but why?

Comment: '&nbsp;' is a good technique as opposed to min-height because it doesn't force a height. Say your font-size is set to 16px and your padding is 15px. Your div will retain the same height before and after text is added to the div (assuming it's all on one line)

Comment: to me, putting a space doesn't work! the div with width 100px and within &nbsp; doesn't look like to be 100px in a div with flex inline elements

Comment: @Luccas or anyone who knows, why does "inline-block" work? I would expect the same behavior with the div's default block.

Answer (score 105):

Either use `padding` , `height` or `&nbsp`  for width to take effect with empty `div`

**EDIT:**

Non zero `min-height` also works great

Comment: I prefer the padding solution, any padding greater than 0 will work. That way you don't have a weird, selectable `&nbsp;` in the `div`.

Comment: Please note: for padding solution you need to provide both left/right ***and*** top/bottom padding for it to work.

Comment: padding didn't work for me, but min-height: 1px

Answer (score 72):

Use `min-height: 1px;`  Everything has at least min-height of 1px so no extra space is taken up with nbsp or padding, or being forced to know the height first.

Comment: Your solutions seems the cleanest to me, but I have been trying to find the reason for this in the CSS spec and I can't find it anywhere, the nearest I found is in `CSS 2.1, 9.5 Floats` where it says `Note: this means that floats with zero outer height or negative outer height do not shorten line boxes.`, but it talks about line boxes i.e. lines in a paragraph, but not about adjacent boxes. Anyone more familiar with CSS spec?

Comment: This worked the best for me. I tried most of the other suggestions on here except &nbsp;.

Comment: If you try this method and it's not working, then in addition to the setting min-height also set display to "block" or "inline-block" and width to 100%. That works for me.

Answer (score 36):

Use CSS to add a zero-width-space to your div. The content of the div will take no room but will force the div to display

```
.test1::before{
   content: "\200B";
}
```

Comment: Seems better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

It has width but no content or height. Add a height attribute to the class test1.

Answer (score 8):

There are different methods to make the empty DIV with `float: left` or `float: right` visible.

Here presents the ones I know:

- set `width`(or `min-width`) with `height` (or `min-height`)
- or set `padding-top`
- or set `padding-bottom`
- or set `border-top`
- or set `border-bottom`
- or use *pseudo-elements*: `::before` or `::after` with:

  - `{content: "\200B";}`
  - or `{content: "."; visibility: hidden;}`
- or put `&nbsp;` inside DIV (this sometimes can bring unexpected effects eg. in combination with `text-decoration: underline;`)

Answer (score 3):

Too late to answer, but nevertheless.

While using CSS, to style the div (content-less), the min-height property must be set to "n"px to make the div visible (works with webkits and chrome, while not sure if this trick will work on IE6 and lower)

Code:

```css
.shape-round{
  width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-round"></div>
```

Comment: min-height isn't necessary, just adding height does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `display:block;` to your test1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I wanted icons to appear by pressing the button but without any movement and sliding the enviroment, just like bulb: on and off, appeared and dissapeared, so I needed to make an empty div with fixed sizes.

```
width: 13px;
min-width: 13px;
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

By defining min *width/hrigh*t for your element you can render it without content:

```html
<div class="your-element"><div>
```

```css
.your-element {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 20px;

  // This is only for observing the element space
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most elegant:

`display: inline-block;`

(credit: [@Luccas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255932/luccas) suggestion in a comment under the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171312/624597))

Answer (score 0):

`&#160;` may do the trick; works in XSL docs

Answer (score 0):

**If** you set `display:` to `inline-block`, `block`, `flex`, ..., on the element with no content, **then**

**For `min-width` to take effect** on a tag with no content, you only need to apply padding for either top **or** bot.

**For `min-height` to take effect** on a tag with no content, you only need to apply padding for left **or** right.

[This example showcases it; here I only sat the padding-left for the `min-width` to take effect on an empty span tag](https://i.gyazo.com/a1c12bbb5e917fcc6de2bb5a3625e4f1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` to assign width and height directly, without any content.

that can easily do it if you are considering a single div.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, my initial css is `width: 5px`, updating it to `min-width: 5px` made the contentless div appear!
No need for extra `height/min-height/padding/display` properties