# Why div can't occupy the desired width space?

Tags: html, css

I found if I specify div with only width CSS attribute, the div will not occupy the width I claimed, see:

```
                <div style="width: 300px;">    
                </div>
```

It will never occupy 300px space.

Is it possible that I want an empty DIV occupies 300px width?

Comment: discussed already :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171286/how-to-make-a-div-no-content-also-have-a-width/4171384#4171384

Comment: Is it possible that you want an empty DIV to occupy 300px? Probably, otherwise you wouldn't have asked :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [See Example](http://jsbin.com/ufoce4)

---

You need to specify something or a space to achieve that:

```
<div style="width:300px; border:1px solid black;">&nbsp;</div>
```

The border was given to show width but you can remove it.

Comment: Is there any other workaround rather than specifying `height` and `empty content(&nbsp)`

Answer (score 3):

You either need to add content or set a `height`. Otherwise an empty div will not appear because its height is determined by its contents.

Comment: Usually I just place in an &nbsp;

Comment: thats a last resort for me. If i can set the height or the min-height then i do that. I hate adding `&nbsp;` as expanding content.

Answer (score 0):

height must be specified in order to make it visible.