# maintain width of span even if nothing in it

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to maintain the width of a span somehow if it is empty?

I have the following HTML pseudo table:

```
<p><span class="col1">Day:</span><span class="col2"><?php echo somephp ?></span></p>
<p><span class="col1">Time:</span><span class="col2"><?php echo somephp ?></span></p>
<p><span class="col1">Class:</span><span class="col2"><?php echo somephp ?></span></p>
<p><span class="col1">Teacher:</span><span class="col2"><?php echo somephp ?></span></p>
```

With CSS:

```
span.col1 {width: 100px;float: left;}
span.col2 {width: 100px;}
```

Sometimes the PHP that is echoed in col2 is empty and when this happens col2's width is 0 and col1 on the paragraph below it ends up stacking up next to col1 in the paragraph above.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171286/how-to-make-a-div-with-no-content-have-a-width

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your `col2` spans are ignoring the width because they are inline elements. You need to make them inline-block elements.

```
span.col2 { width: 100px; display: inline-block }
```

Also keep in mind that you *may* need to add a height to it depending on where it's displayed, or you'll end up with a span 100px wide but 0px high.

Comment: Just a precision : with <span class="col2"></span>, the span take the good width. But <span class="col2"/> is not visible. I don't understand. 2 are empty no ?

Comment: I also had to add a height property to the span css otherwise it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

By default `span` displays as inline.

So either add `display:block` to give it a block element or additionally you could use `display:inline-block` to keep it inline with the rest of the text (without using `float`).

Answer (score 2):

By default span element is an inline element, and it ignores width.

Try adding display:block to your spans.

```
span.col1 {width: 100px;float: left; display:block;}
span.col2 {width: 100px; display:block;}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `display:block;` adds a line break.

Comment: That is correct, but question was how to have spans maintain width with empty content. And I have suggested using block because older browsers IE8- don't work with inline-block.

Comment: Older browsers typically don't work with inline-block if by default the element is displayed as a block. However, if the element is natively inline, e.g. `span` then it will work fine.