# How to show an empty DIV with dynamic width?

Tags: html, css

how can I make an empty DIV or SPAN to be shown and grow or shrink according to the content of the others?

This is what I have until now:

```css
.text{
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
}
.borda{
 display:inline-block;
 background-image: url('borda.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-position:center bottom;
 float:left;
 margin:30px 0 0 5px;
 empty-cells: show;"
}
.numbers{
 float:right;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="text">Text Text Text</span><span class"borda"></span><span class="numbers">Numbers</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171286/how-to-make-a-div-with-no-content-have-a-width

Comment: Do you want to make a "borda" grow because of "numbers" ?

Comment: `empty-cells: show;"` what's that `"`?

Comment: `class"borda"` should be `class="borda"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan about empty-cells take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_empty-cells.asp

Comment: @stratovarius "borda" will grow or shrink depending on the size of "text", "numbers" will always have seven chars (by the way... great band!)

Comment: @Heathz what's w3schools? P.S: I was referring to your typo `"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just mistyped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS3 flexbox specifications. Simply allow the `.borda` container to grow, i.e. `flex-grow: 1`. I have changed the background colours to show contrast. There is some error with your markup, including the missing `=` for the class assignment for `.borda`.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
.text {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.borda {
  background-color: #333;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.numbers {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text">Text Text Text</span><span class="borda"></span><span class="numbers">Numbers</span>
</div>
```